# Can we update links to BrewAdvice?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, brewadvice.com

There are comments / links in older posts from BrewAdvice that link to the wrong ID on the current site. Is there a way to update these programmatically, or do we have to go in and fix them ourselves?

Example: [Immersion chiller or counter-flow chiller?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/immersion-chiller-or-counter-flow-chiller/1603#1603)

Answer (score 3):

Below are a list of posts / comments that have a link to BrewAdvice.com - there's no great way of automatically linking these so the effort will be manual

<strike>https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/658    post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/797    post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/847    comment

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/864    comment

[What's the difference between primary & secondary fermentation?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/866)    post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/898    post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/915    post</strike>


[Storing bottle conditioned beers and carbonation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/952)    comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/981    comment


<strike>https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/981    post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1000   post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1119   post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1155   post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1188   post</strike>


https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1213   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1215   comment

<strike>https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1239   post</strike>


[Wet Crushing Grain](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1250)   comment

<strike>https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1273   post

https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1281   post</strike>


[Gelatin for clearer beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1297)   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1311   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Equipment Storage](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1330)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Mashing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1331)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Steeping](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1332)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Boiling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1333)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: The Chill](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1334)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Fermentation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1335)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Packaging](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1336)   post
[Small Space & Apartment Brewing: Cellaring](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1337)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1344   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1350   post
[Beer Pairing: Stuffed Shells with Tomato Sauce](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1366)   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1384   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1423   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1426   post
[Using Grolsch "Premium Lager" bottles for bottling](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1431)   comment
[Massively Over-Carbonated Beer...What Do I Do?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1436)   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1510   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1511   comment
[Harvesting commercial yeast](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1519)   post
[What is conversion?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1521)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1541   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1543   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1553   post
[When should I add a vanilla bean?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1561)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1603   comment
[Improving Your Brewing Significantly](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1617)   comment
[Improving Your Brewing Significantly](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1617)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1625   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1672   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1689   post
[Would/Could you add boiled, rehydrated extract after wort is cooled & topped off to boost OG?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1710)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1712   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1721   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1760   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1771   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1784   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1795   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1797   post
[Why is it bad to pitch too much yeast?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1807)   post
[Why is it bad to pitch too little yeast?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1812)   post
[How do you filter at home?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1815)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1831   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1855   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1898   post
[Using commercial (breakfast) cereals in a mash](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1957)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1985   post
[Detriment of gelatin fining on flavor or aroma](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2035)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2052   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2063   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2067   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2088   post
[why do you degas wine but not beer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2114)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2133   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2142   post
[Bottling kegged beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2155)   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2192   post
[Didn't hit gravity--how to calculate how much malt extract to add to the fermenter?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2231)   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2232   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2236   comment
[Calculating sugar in fresh fruit](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2271)   comment
[Shipping beer to fellow brewers](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2278)   comment
[Drying freshly picked hops](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2354)   post
[Using force carbing, how long does 5 lbs CO2 last you?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2381)   comment
[Ported carboy vs. siphoning?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2397)   comment
[Preparing Cherries for Secondary](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2462)   post
[Pumpkin Spiced beer](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2515)   comment
[Capturing wild yeasts?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2518)   comment
[Too much Irish moss?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2543)   post
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2567   comment
https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2620   comment

Comment: I'm going to start doing these and crossing them off the list. Any other admins, please lend a hand.

Comment: @PJ would it be helpful for those of us without edit access to help out too?  Is it easier for you to approve an edit than actually editing?

Comment: @PJ All posts up through ID 1300 (not comments) are done (currently as suggested-edits). Can you wikify this? I don't have the option to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moderator at tex.stackexchange.com and we always do that by hand. I'm not aware of any scripting or other solution which would avoid that and don't think there is any.